# JavaScript: Optimize function to create a vertical timeline

Tags: javascript, for-loop, timeline

I created a simple function to iterate through a for loop and display a vertical timeline. 
Can I get some opinions on what I've created so far?

Are there ways to improve/optimize what I've created so far?

Ideally, what I'm after are ways to minimize duplications, extraneous calls, etc.

Here's my working code: http://jsfiddle.net/bL25b/

```
function timeline( start, abbr, hours )
{
  var a = 0,
      start,
      abbr,
      hours,
      time = document.getElementById('timeline');

  hours = (!hours) ? 12 : hours;

  for(a = a + start; a <= hours + start; a++)
  {
    if(a > 12)
    {
      time.innerHTML += '<li>' + (a - 12) + ':00 ' +
                          ( abbr == 'AM' ? 'PM' : 'AM' ) +
                        '</li>';

      time.innerHTML += '<li>' + (a - 12) + ':30 ' +
                          ( abbr == 'PM' ? 'AM' : 'PM' ) +
                        '</li>';
    }
    else
    {
      time.innerHTML += '<li>' + a + ':00 ' +
                          ( abbr == 'AM' ? (a == 12) ? 'PM' : 'AM' : 'PM' ) +
                        '</li>';

      time.innerHTML += '<li>' + a + ':30 ' +
                          ( abbr == 'AM' ? (a == 12) ? 'PM' : 'AM' : 'PM' ) +
                        '</li>';
    }
  }
}

timeline( 9, 'AM', 12 );
```

The function arguments that are accepted:

- start: start time (0-12)
- abbr: Am/PM abbreviation
- hours: number of hours to display

Comment: Why are you declaring variables with the same names as the parameters? Why initialise a to 0 and then add start later? (Just initialise it to start in the first place.) You could add start  to hours before the loop instead of doing the sum on every iteration.

Comment: you should post it to `codereview.stackchange`

Comment: Thanks @Jordan! Good things to consider and change.

@Wong2 I did not know that existed. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the [updated code](http://jsfiddle.net/bL25b/3/):

```
function timeline( start, abbr, hours )
{
    var a = 0,
        abbr = abbr || 'AM',
        hours = hours || 12,
        time = document.getElementById('timeline'),
        timelineHTML = [];

    for (a = a + start; a <= hours + start; a++)
    {
        if (a % 12 === 0) {
            abbr = abbr === 'PM' ? 'AM' : 'PM';
        }

        timelineHTML.push('<li>' + (a % 12 === 0 ? 12 : a % 12) + ':00 ' + abbr + '</li>');
        timelineHTML.push('<li>' + (a % 12 === 0 ? 12 : a % 12) + ':30 ' + abbr + '</li>');
    }

    time.innerHTML = timelineHTML.join('');
}

timeline( 9, 'AM', 24 );
```

The most significant change is minifying the DOM operations — we store our future elements in an array and append them at once.

Secondly, I removed unnecessary and confusing `if..else` block. The change between 'AM' and 'PM' occures every 12 hours, so a simple modulus operatior will do.

The part where `(a % 12 === 0 ? 12 : a % 12)` might be still confusing, but it is kept to display **12:30 AM** instead of **0:30 AM**. You can change it to short `(a % 12)` if you want.

Finally, you used `hours = (!hours) ? 12 : hours`, while simple `hours = hours || 12` is more readable.

Comment: Truly flushed out. Thank you. This is why I wanted to get fresh opinions about what I've created. I am taking all of the changes/suggestions here and working up a new function. However, your sample pretty sums it all up :)

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `innerHTML +=` every time, use an array to store the html partials, then use `join`  method to join them to a string and assign the string to `innerHTML`

Comment: Excellent advice, thank you! There is a code example below that does what you posted here. Thank you :D

Answer (score 2):

Instead of innerHTML , use:

1. `createElement` - to create new LI element
2. `insertAfter` - to insert it in the end

To add new node to existing one.
That would be faster than adding innerHTML to existing innerHTML.

Comment: Is it true? what I remember is that use `innerHTML` would be faster than manipulate the dom with those methods

Comment: @DhruvPathak I hadn't considered creating an element dynamically because of the overhead versus just adding the `<li></li>` tags within the code.

@Wong2 I believe so as well.

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to touch an element's innerHTML, it's usually considered optimal to do so all at once. In addition, your existing for loop has to process the addition every time, and it's best to define the finish point of the loop beforehand.

```
var newHTML = '';
var finish = hours+start;

for(a=a+start; a <= finish; a++)
{
    if(a > 12)
    {
        newHTML += '<li>' + (a-12) + ':00 ' + ( abbr == 'AM' ? 'PM' : 'AM' ) + '</li>';
        newHTML += '<li>' + (a-12) + ':30 ' + ( abbr == 'PM' ? 'AM' : 'PM' ) + '</li>';
    }
    else
    {
       newHTML += '<li>' + a + ':00 ' + ( abbr == 'AM' ? (a==12) ? 'PM' : 'AM' : 'PM' ) + '</li>';
       newHTML += '<li>' + a + ':30 ' + ( abbr == 'AM' ? (a==12) ? 'PM' : 'AM' : 'PM' ) + '</li>';
   }
}

time.innerHTML += newHTML;
```

Comment: The timeline will display wrong results for 25+ hours, e.g. 13:00, 14:00, etc.

Comment: @Luke Dennis Thank you! I like the waiting to unload until it's finished idea.

Comment: @Lapple good point. However, the timeline is not meant to go beyond the 24 hour mark...which technically is 11:59PM. But good catch. I should incorporate some logic to account for that to either stop at midnight or add another day's worth of increments.

Comment: @Lapple Your code sample below indeed takes into account 25+!! Most excellent :D

Answer (score 1):

Everyone else covered the broad strokes (@Lapple especially), so here's a couple very minor low-hanging items:

```
hours = (!hours) ? 12 : hours;
```

Can be shortened to:

```
hours = hours || 12;
```

...and is a more readable idiom (I think) to most JavaScript programmers.

#### Edit re: your comment:

I don't know of a name for this particular idiom. Like most programming languages JavaScript uses [short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) on boolean expressions, i.e. given `X || Y` if the interpreter can already tell the value of expression will be from `X` (because `X` is "truthy"), it never bothers to evaluate `Y`. So you could do something like `true || delete_everything()` confident that `delete_everything` would never be called. Likewise in `X && Y` if `X` is "falsy" then `Y` will never be evaluated.

This might all be old hat to you. What JavaScript does that's less common, though, is what you could call "last value" evaluation (this is the term the Wikipedia page uses but I'm not sure if it's a common term at all). Instead of returning `true` or `false` from a boolean expression as in Java, or `1` or `0` as in C, in JavaScript it just returns the *last value* evaluated.

Take the expression `hours || 12`. If `hours` is `undefined` (a falsy value in JavaScript), then the interpreter will just return the second operand (since in an `OR` the "truthiness" of the expression is always equal to the truthiness of the second operand when the first operand is falsy). However, if `hours` is truthy--say, `9` or `"banana"`, then the expression will short-circuit after evaluating it and return that value. To repeat myself, but in code:

```
var hours; // declared but has the value undefined

console.log( hours || 12 ); // `hours` (undefined) is falsy
// => 12                    // so return the second operand

hours = 9;
console.log( hours || 12 ); // `hours` is truthy--short-circuit & return `hours`
// => 9

hours = "banana";
console.log( hours || 12 ); // `"banana"` is also truthy
// => "banana";

console.log( 12 || hours ); // `12` is truth--short-circuit & return `12`
// => 12
```

Incidentally, in languages like Ruby that have the `||=` operator, there's an even shorter form of this idiom that's fairly common:

```
hours = nil          # `nil` is like `null`

hours = hours || 12  # just like in JavaScript
# => 12

# but the below is equivalent:

hours = nil

hours ||= 12
# => 12
```

So in Ruby it's not uncommon to see methods like this:

```
def foo(bar, baz = nil) # `baz` defaults to `nil` when no 2nd argument is given
  baz ||= get_default_baz()

  puts bar + baz        # `puts` is like `print` or `echo` in other languages
end

def get_default_baz     # a trivial example
  "WXYZ"
end

foo('ABC', 'DEF')
# => ABCDEF

foo('ABC')
# => ABCWXYZ
```

#### (End edit)

And here:

```
var a = 0,
    start,
    abbr,
    hours,
    time = document.getElementById('timeline');

hours = (!hours) ? 12 : hours;
```

...you're declaring `hours` on line 4 and then assigning it on line 7, when you could do both at the same time:

```
var a = 0,
    // ...
    hours = hours || 12
    // ...
;
```

Comment: I fully agree with what you've pointed out. I am now using this method myself. Thank you!

Comment: is there a specific JS programming name for  this method: x = x || num;

Comment: @JsusSalv Since I'm really wordy I edited my answer to answer your comment. Take a look.

Comment: Here's my updated code. What do you think: http://jsfiddle.net/bL25b/6/

Any other improvements/optimizations?

Comment: I like wordy! :) Helps me understand and improve my skills. Thank you!!